# SugarCRM Querying Database

Tags: sugarcrm

In SugarCRM, using SOAP API, imagining i have lots of accounts populated in the database, and i want to find the account that has `'phone_work' = '00352254856987'`. How can i make a query to accomplish that? It would be something like this:?

```
    $query = "phone_work = '${myPhone}'";
```

For what i have tried, it seems the compiler finds an error in the XML document, which means the query is not well executed. What is the best way to do this kind of queries?

I'm using magento and creating a module to connect to sugar, so it is PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the field `'phone_work'` is wrong. You can access at: http://apidocs.sugarcrm.com/schema/6.3.0/pro/tables/accounts.html and get all the fields related to that module. In the module `'Accounts`', the field name is called `'office phone'`, but in the database, the name is `'phone_office'`. Because the query is for the database, we need to use database field names.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the error that you get? Take also a look at the sugarcrm.log and maybe increase the logging level to see if the sql that gets created from your query is wrong. 
By the way I switched to REST Json to get rid of soap related problems.